# Shell UNIX : grep wild card

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, wildcard

I can't figure out why the wild character * is interpreted differently in the following examples with grep :

```
find . -type f -name \*
```

Results :

```
./tgt/etc/test_file.c
./tgt/etc/speleo/test_file.c
./tgt/etc/other_file.c
./src/file.c
```

I want to return from this command the files that match a pattern with eventually a wildcard *. But :

```
find . -type f -name \* | grep "tgt/etc/*" # this one works
find . -type f -name \* | grep tgt/etc/* # not this one
find . -type f -name \* | grep tgt/et*/s* # this one works
find . -type f -name \* | grep "tgt/et*/s*" # not this one
```

I'd like to have an implementation which works fine with both cases. What should I use ?

Comment: You understand that `*` works differently in regular expressions than it does in filename wildcards, right?

Comment: looking at the question, I guess he does not :-)

Comment: @Barmar I may be missing something, but don't see how that has anything to do with the question. The problem is how [tag:grep] process arguments, meaning `grep file1 file2`, won't match both `file1` and `file2`.

Comment: Yes, I realized this question was more complicated after I posted that comment; see my answer.

Comment: That's the issue with his unquoted greps, my comment is more relevant for his quoted greps, because they don't use `*` correctly.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the different uses of * between shell as wildcard and regexp as a quantifier. Or at least, I didn't even think about it. Your answers permit me to solve my problem by using a full regular expression : grep "tgt/et.*/s.*" for example. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to `grep` is not a wildcard, it's a regular expression. In a regular expression, `*` means to match any number of the character or expression that precedes it. So

```
grep "tgt/etc/*"
```

means to match `tgt/etc` followed by zero or more `/` characters. In a wildcard, `*` means to match any number of any characters, the equivalent regular expression is `.*`. For your purposes, the commands you want are:

```
find . -type f -name \* | grep "tgt/etc/"
find . -type f -name \* | grep "tgt/et.*/s"
```

Also, if you don't quote the argument, and it contains any `*` characters, the shell will expand the argument as a filename wildcard before passing them as arguments to `grep`. So when you write:

```
find . -type f -name \* | grep tgt/etc/*
```

the shell will expand this to

```
find . -type f -name \* | grep tgt/etc/file1 tgt/etc/file2 tgt/etc/file3
```

This will treat the `tgt/etc/file1` as the regular expression to search for, and look for it inside the remaining files -- it will *not* process the input from the pipeline because it was given filename arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The unquoted examples (without the `"`) are expanded by the shell, before `grep` ever sees them. That is just the way Unix shells work.

For the quoted ones, note that `*` in a grep pattern means something different from what it means to the shell and to `find`: It means “repeat the preceding character any number of times (including zero).”

Answer (score 1):

it's because `grep` uses regexps and no wildcards.

so basically, what you do is:

- `tgt/etc/*` checking zero or sereval `/`
- `tgt/et*/s*` checking zero or several `t` and zero or several `s`

but thing is that when you do not put quotes around the regexp, the shell is expanding the `*` as wildcards, which messes up the regexp grep sees.